# How can I retrieve all related records in this case?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the gem called 'mailboxer', which provides messaging system within App.
(https://github.com/ging/mailboxer)

I can retrieve current_user's messages by coding like this

```
@messages = current_user.mailbox.inbox.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

What if I want to retrieve all messages for admin mode?
How can I code it?

I tried this

```
@users = User.find(:all)
@messages = @users.mailbox.inbox.page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

However, it gave this error back:(

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `mailbox' for #<Array:0x0000001976ce38>):
  app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:55:in `admin_mode'
```

Comment: That's not working because User.find(:all) will give you an array of users. You either need to try Mailbox.inbox.page... or something like @users.first.mailbox... Or find a specific admin user?

Comment: @simonmorley Thanks I tried `Mailbox.inbox.page(params[:page]).per(10)`, however it still says this `NoMethodError (undefined method `inbox' for Mailbox:Class):`

Comment: Ok, sorry. In which case you need something like Mailbox.find(123).inbox. If you need all messages in the all the inboxes, try Inbox.all ?

Comment: @simonmorley Thanks:) I tried this `@messages = Inbox.all.page(params[:page]).per(10)`, but now it says this error back `NameError (uninitialized constant MessagesController::Inbox):`

Comment: There's other ways to skin this cat but I can't see your associations or models. Eg. You might want to create a scope to find messages related to admin users. Could you edit your question and include your controllers and models pls. I'm not familier with mailboxer or the setup.

Comment: @simonmorley Thanks for reply:) I haven't done any at all with association, and controller. That's pretty much all about with codes I wrote in my question. Because, once I bundled this gem, it takes everything at all so that I didn't need to do any. I don't even have `models/messages.rb` Could you think of any other way to retrieve all messages?

Comment: I can't see anything in mailboxer repository that discusses all messages. Have you tried Message.all for all the messages as there doesn't appear to be a model called Inbox. (Should you be reading all you users email btw:)

Comment: @simonmorley I tried `@messages = Message.all.page(params[:page]).per(10)`, now it says  `NoMethodError (undefined method `page' for #<Array:0x000000136a3c50>):`

Comment: What does Message.all do?

Comment: @simonmorley you mean without `.page(params[:page]).per(10)`?

Comment: Yup. The paginate gem doesn't handle arrays out of the box.

Comment: @simonmorley Thanks now it fetches records. But I cannot use pagination. Isn't it possible to use pagination?

Comment: Yeah you can, you just need to enable it in the will_paginate gem. Do a search on SO and you'll find a tonne of stuff. S

Comment: @simonmorley Thanks. I'm using Kaminari. Isn't it possible to use Kaminari instead?

Comment: Not sure, you'd need to read the docs. Good luck, hope I've helped.